# How to change inline js

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, prototype-js

```
<li class="buttons ajaxlogin_actions">
                            <button id="ajaxlogin_button_send" name="ajaxlogin_button_send" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" class="button ajaxlogin_button ajaxlogin_actions" type="button" onclick="AjaxLoginForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__("Login") ?></span></span></button>
                            <a class="ajaxlogin_actions2" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>customer/account/create/"><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></a>
                            <a id="ajaxlogin_forgot_pwd_link" class="ajaxlogin_actions" href="javascript:AjaxLoginForm.showForgotPwdForm('ajaxlogin_form_pwd', 'ajaxlogin_is_forgot_pwd')"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Password') ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="buttons ajaxlogin_forgot_pwd_actions" style="display:none;">
                            <button id="ajaxlogin_button_forgot_pwd" name="ajaxlogin_button_forgot_pwd" title="<?php echo $this->__("Forgot Password") ?>" class="button ajaxlogin_button ajaxlogin_forgot_pwd_actions" type="button" onclick="AjaxLoginForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__("Forgot Password") ?></span></span></button>
                            <a id="ajaxlogin_link" class="ajaxlogin_forgot_pwd_actions" 
                            href="javascript:AjaxLoginForm.showLoginForm('ajaxlogin_form_pwd', 'ajaxlogin_is_forgot_pwd')"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></a>

                        </li>
```

I want to change `href="javascript:AjaxLoginForm.showLoginForm('ajaxlogin_form_pwd', 'ajaxlogin_is_forgot_pwd')"`  to `onClick="AjaxLoginForm.showLoginForm('ajaxlogin_form_pwd', 'ajaxlogin_is_forgot_pwd')"` my main goal is to remove the inline js but when I am doing it onClick it's not working.

Here is the js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
            var AjaxLoginForm = new VarienForm("ajaxlogin_form");
            AjaxLoginForm.submit = function(button){
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    // show ajax image
                    // button.insert({"after":osc_ajax_loading_small});
                    AjaxLoginForm.hideLoader();
                    AjaxLoginForm.insertLoader(button);

                    $("ajaxlogin_form").request({
                        onSuccess: function(transport) {
                            var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

                            if(json.is_forgot_pwd){
                                if(json.success){
                                    $("ajaxlogin_form_message").update("<span style='color:green;font-weight:bold'>"+json.success_message+"</span>");
                                    $("ajaxlogin_form_message").show();
                                }
                                if(json.error){
                                    $("ajaxlogin_form_message").update("<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>"+json.error_message+"</span>");
                                    $("ajaxlogin_form_message").show();
                                }
                            }else{                          
                                if(json.success){
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                                if(json.error){
                                    $("ajaxlogin_form_message").update("<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>"+json.error_message+"</span>");
                                    $("ajaxlogin_form_message").show();
                                }
                            }
                            AjaxLoginForm.hideLoader();
                            setTimeout("AjaxLoginForm.hideResponseMessage()", 5000);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }.bind(AjaxLoginForm);

            AjaxLoginLoader = "<div class='ajax_login_loader'>&nbsp;</div>";
            AjaxLoginForm.insertLoader = function(element){
                // show ajax image
                element.insert({"after":AjaxLoginLoader});
            }

            AjaxLoginForm.hideLoader = function(){
                $$(".ajax_login_loader").each(function(elem){
                    elem.remove();
                });
            }

            AjaxLoginForm.showForgotPwdForm = function(pwdFieldId, forgotPwdFlagFieldId){
                $(pwdFieldId).toggle( "blind" );
                $(forgotPwdFlagFieldId).value = 1;

                $$("li.ajaxlogin_forgot_pwd_actions").each(function(elem){
                    elem.toggle( "blind" );
                });

                $$("li.ajaxlogin_actions").each(function(elem){
                    elem.toggle( "blind" );
                });
            }

            AjaxLoginForm.showLoginForm = function(pwdFieldId, forgotPwdFlagFieldId){
                $(pwdFieldId).toggle( "blind" );
                $(forgotPwdFlagFieldId).value = 0;

                $$("li.ajaxlogin_actions").each(function(elem){
                    elem.toggle( "blind" );
                });

                $$("li.ajaxlogin_forgot_pwd_actions").each(function(elem){
                    elem.toggle( "blind" );
                });
            }
            AjaxLoginForm.hideLoginContainer = function(){
                $$('ul.popup').each(function(containerEl){
                    containerEl.style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("dullDiv").style.display = "none";
                });
            }

            AjaxLoginForm.hideResponseMessage = function(){
                $('ajaxlogin_form_message').toggle( "blind" );
                setTimeout("$('ajaxlogin_form_message').innerHTML = '';", 3000);
            }
            $$('ul.popup').each(function(containerEl){
                containerEl.style.display = "none";
            });

        function openLogin(){
            document.getElementById("dullDiv").style.display = "block";
            setDivPosition('loginPopupDiv');
        }
        function setDivPosition(divId){  // USED TO SET POSITION OF DIV
            var DivShowed = document.getElementById(divId)
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop
            var myHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : (document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : (document.body.clientHeight ? document.body.clientHeight : 0))
            var clientWid = document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.clientWidth;
            DivShowed.style.left = ((clientWid-DivShowed.offsetWidth)/2)+'px'; 
            DivShowed.style.top = ((parseInt(myHeight) - DivShowed.offsetHeight)/2)+'px';
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```